# SonarLint doesn't use SonarQube server rules that come from a plugin

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I've configured a server binding between SonarQube and Intellij and it's working fine on "usual" rules. I tested it: I changed the severity of a JavaScript rule in the quality profile of the project in SonarQube, updated the binding in Intellij, and saw the new severity in Intellij on-the-fly report. Alright.
The problem is I also need SonarQube rules that come from its plugins. For example, I have TypeScript and CSS rules that come from plugins. My SonarQube analysis report 1000+ bugs, but SonarLint within Intellij reports 0 bug.
Is there a way of exporting this rules from SonarQube into Intellij?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I guess I've found the answer... See question #5 of [SonarLint's FAQ](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/index.html#FAQ):

> We don't plan to support plugins running third-party analyzers (like
>   PMD, Android Lint, JSLint...). Most of the time those analyzers
>   already have dedicated IDE integration.

Too bad though, because we wanted to share our SonarQube quality profiles all over the company...

Answer (score 0):

Thats funy cause : 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Configuring+SonarQube+in+IntelliJ

> The SonarQube IntelliJ plugin is deprecated The SonarQube IntelliJ
>   plugin does not work with SonarQube 5.2+. It is replaced by SonarLint
>   for IntelliJ.